# Flutter packages not recognised in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Flutter(1.22.5) packages are not recognized in Android Studio(Windows-10(64bit)),eventhough they are available in the `"C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib"` directory.
How to resolve this?

Flutter path - C:\src\flutter
DartSdk path - C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk

Packages -

```
C:\src\flutter>cd "C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib"

C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2EAF-73E1

 Directory of C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib

16-Dec-20  04:43 PM    <DIR>          .
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM    <DIR>          ..
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             3,076 analysis_options_user.yaml
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             9,707 animation.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             2,024 cupertino.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             1,777 foundation.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             1,216 gestures.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             6,018 material.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             2,464 painting.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM               677 physics.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             3,170 rendering.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM               694 scheduler.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM               707 semantics.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             1,664 services.dart
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM    <DIR>          src
16-Dec-20  04:43 PM             5,308 widgets.dart
              13 File(s)         38,502 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  27,227,918,336 bytes free
```

main.dart -

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\material.dart';
```

ERROR -

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'flutter' in 'package:flutter/material.dart'.

       ^
lib/main.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'package:flutter/material.dart'
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:7:8: Error: Error when reading 'c:src%0Clutterpackages%0Clutterlibmaterial.dart': StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs
import 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\material.dart';
```

Comment: have you set up environment variable correctly?

Comment: Under User-Environment variables added paths - "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin" & "C:\src\flutter\bin".Any other paths required?

Comment: looks okay, is vs code giving same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original project was created by downloading Flutter via Git ,maybe the latest Flutter version has some bugs.

Downloading Flutter stable version from the official website  solved the issue.